# Implementing Toggle button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on amazon like website.

It gives the option to a logged-in user (on the item show page) to add an item to the cart if the item is not in the cart already. The user clicks on '`Add to cart`' button and the item is added to cart, but the user still remains on the item's show page.

If the item is already added to the cart, it instead shows '`Remove from Cart`' button. When the user clicks the button, the item is removed from the cart but the user is not redirected to a new page. He remains on the item's show page.

I am new to Rails, so I have been trying many ways to make this work.

Code:

/app/models/user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

/app/models/item.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

/app/controllers/items_controller.rb

```
def add_to_cart
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user
  @user.items << @item
  render 'show'
end

def remove_from_cart
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user
  @user.items.delete(@item)
  render 'show'
end
```

/app/views/items/show.rb

```
<tr>
  <% if user_signed_in? then %>
    <% if  !current_user.items.include?(@item)then %>
      <%= button_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_path(:id => @item.id) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= button_to "Remove from Cart", remove_from_cart_path(:id => @item.id ) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>  
</tr>
```

/config/routes.rb

```
post '/items/:id/add_to_cart' => 'items#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'

post '/items/:id/remove_from_cart' => 'items#remove_from_cart' , :as => 'remove_from_cart'
```

---

Although on clicking 'Add to Cart' button, the item gets added in the cart and remains on the item show page, but it changes the url from

```
http://localhost:3000/items/2
```

to

```
http://localhost:3000/items/2/add_to_cart
```

Any idea how can it remain the same?
Also, please let me know if there are any alternate solutions.

Comment: Please show us your attempted solutions at this problem.

Comment: You should try using ajax calls to do that, the Agile Web Development with Rails book, which comes out with basically every Rails release covers implementing a shopping cart incrementally, which should guide you through the basics and end up with what your trying to do. Now a days its not the best entrance book, but for a step by tep shopping cart deal, it should work.